# Trying to save the search in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am basically using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) for my little application.

I want the ability to save a search. For instance say i have a table with name of colors and quantity. If i type red it will filter out the searches and show the color red and its respective quantity. Now if i go to a different page and come back to the DataTable page i want that result and search to still be there.

So i did a little research and found out there is something called save state which can be set to true to get this result. Source: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html

However it wont't work for me. I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Following is my code

```
function ttable_draw_table(table_object,event_callback_function,target,args){
  var title = table_object.name.split('-').slice(1).join(' ');
  var title = title.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+title.slice(1);
  var header = '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-2"><a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="#!/'+table_object.data.add+'/" style="width:100%"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> New</a></div>';
  header += '<div class="col-sm-7"><h1 style="margin:0px;">'+title+'</h1></div>';
  //header += '<div class="col-sm-2 hidden-xs"><a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" href="csv/all" style="width:100%"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></i> CSV</a></div>';
  header += '<div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs"><a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="ttable-clear-filter" style="width:100%"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></i> Clear Search</a></div></div>';
  target.html(header+'<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-striped" id="ttable-'+table_object.name+'" ></table></div>');
  rowString = '<thead><tr>';

  //This is the CODE TO SAVE THE SEARCH
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ttable').dataTable( {
        stateSave: true
    } );
} );



  for (var column_index in table_object.data.columns) {
    rowString += '<th>'+table_object.data.columns[column_index]+'</th>';
  }
  rowString += '</tr></thead>';
  $('#ttable-'+table_object.name).append(rowString);


  rowString = '<tbody>';
  for (var row in table_object.data.rows) {
    rowString += '<tr rowid="'+row+'">';
    for (var column_index in table_object.data.columns) {
      if (table_object.data.rows[row][column_index] == null) {
        table_object.data.rows[row][column_index] = 'TBD';
      }
      rowString+='<td>'+table_object.data.rows[row][column_index]+'</td>';
    }
    rowString += '</tr>';
  }
  rowString += '</tbody>';
  $('#ttable-'+table_object.name).append(rowString);

  if (args.search === undefined) { args.search = ''; }
  $('#ttable-'+table_object.name).dataTable({
    iDisplayLength: 50, 
    fnRowCallback: function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
      $(nRow).on('click', function() {
        event_callback_function(table_object, $(this).attr('rowid'));
      });
    }
  }).fnFilter(args.search);

  $('#ttable-clear-filter').click(function() {
    $('#ttable-'+table_object.name).dataTable().fnFilter('');
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you using v1.10? I see that your initialisation code has a lowercase `d` in dataTable...

Comment: stateSave is a v1.10 feature: [datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave)

Comment: @markpsmith is there anyway to achieve that result in 1.9 ?

Comment: I've seen `fnSaveState` for 1.9, but I've no idea how to use it: [legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnStateSave](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnStateSave)

Comment: fnSaveState === stateSave, it stores exactly the same information.

Comment: @davidkonrad so i just have to replace stateSave with fnSaveState?

Comment: No, It was nonsense what I wrote :) I mean `bStateSave` is the 1.9.x equivalence of course!! See this demo -> http://jsfiddle.net/8qL33kua/ try sort on a column and move some pages forward, and then right click and reload the iframe  (the iframe bottom right) You can see the state is stored in localstorage under dev tools->resources->local storage (at least in Chrome)

Comment: @davidkonrad , Demo is working beautifully can you possibly suggest what i should do in my code..and also post it as answer so i can accept it

Comment: @davidkonrad i am still not able to do this. any suggestion?

Comment: You should just add `bStateSave : true` instead of `stateSave: true`

Comment: Follow this tutorial, you will find all the answers there http://refreshmymind.com/datatables-state-save-client-server-side/